# android google play service

Tags: android, gmail, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

Actually i am new android user currently facing one problem from a while [this is](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html#choose)
 the link where u can see the code provided by google.
its showing me red line on GoogleAuthUtil in eclipse. please help me out.

```
   private String[] getAccountNames() {
    AccountManager mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(
            GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    String[] names = new String[accounts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        names[i] = accounts[i].name;
    }
    return names;
}
```

Comment: what does the red line says when you hover your mouse over it ? or click the red cross on the left side and see what does it say.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) to setup Google Play Services in your project.

After that, you can import GoogleAuthUtil normally.

Answer (score 0):

## Sayed.jalil:-

its showing "Google.AuthUtil cannot be resolved" and
its also giving error in import statement..
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
showing red line on "com.google" nd error is "the import com.google cannot be resolved"